How to export a pdf with ExportAsFixedFormat(), without resaving, if the Excel file is on cloud storage
I have an Excel sheet with macros. I export a pdf of a sheet using the following code:
Public Sub NowPrintThePage(ByVal LieferantPdfName As String)
    PdfName = Sheets(LieferantPdfName).Range("F16").Value & " " & Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 10)
    Sheets(LieferantPdfName).ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=PdfName, _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub

I do not save the pdf file. I open it, from a folder within Windows, such that the user can decide what to do with it.
If I open the Excel file from cloud storage (OneDrive, MS Teams, etc.), the macro throws an exception at the line with ExportAsFixedFormat(...).
My guess is, that Excel tries to save the pdf before displaying to the folder of the Excel file - which is not possible because it is loaded from the cloud.
Since I do not want to save the pdf file, what can I do to generate the pdf and show it to the user, even if on the cloud?

Save it to the user's Temp folder?  It has to go somewhere

How do I know the users Temp folder?

The file is actually not saved when I run it from a directory. When the generation works, the pdf is opened, but not saved to any folder. It is just my guess, that Excel tries to save it, maybe even does and deletes it directly afterwards. But since it can't save it, it fails. I don't want to save the file anywhere. I just want to make the export work if it's called from a cloud.

Get the user's TEMP folder with this VBA function:  ENVIRON("TMP")

That worked for my case - many thanks! My working code is: PdfName = Environ("TMP") & "\" & Sheets(Lief...
